# Reutilizar hilos / Iniciar hilo luego de que el otro termine

Tags: c#, bucle-for, hilos, datagridview

soy nuevo en la utilización de hilos.
Ocurre que en la aplicación que estoy desarrollando al presionar un botón recorro los datos de un DataGridView con lo cual obtengo cadenas que valido en el bucle for mediante un case.
Como la columna que recorro del DataGridView puede contener distintos valores debo ejecutar un hilo por cada distinto resultado, lo que ocurre es que no se la manera en la que puedo ejecutar los hilos en orden, es decir que se ejecute uno y luego otro dependiendo de los resultados obtenidos del DGV. Adjunto el codigo

```
private void btnImportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // String que será de parametro para los hilos

            DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila  in dgvTabla.Rows)
            {
                             
                string ruta = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["ruta"].Value);
                string tabla = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["tabla"].Value);
                string[] parametros = { ruta };

                switch (tabla)
                {
                    case "detmov":    
                        // Vaciamos el hilo
                        Hilo01 = null;
                        // Para pasar parametros a un hilo
                        Hilo01 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Detmov));
                        // Iniciamos el hilo
                        Hilo01.Start(parametros);
                        break;
                    case "almacen":
                        Hilo01 = null;
                        Hilo01 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Almacen));
                        Hilo01.Start(parametros);
                        break;
                    case "movimien":
                        Hilo01 = null;
                        Hilo01 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Movimien));
                        Hilo01.Start(parametros);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                
                parametros = null;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Si quieres utilizar los hilos uno detrás de otro no te sirve de nada usar hilos, es incluso contraproducente. Ejecuta el código secuencialmente y ya está.

Comment: Bueno lo que sucede es que son consultas grandes y la aplicación me solicita que use hilos para que no se congele

Comment: Entonces usa solo un hilo para toda la ejecución.

Comment: Utilizando el hilo principal me mandaba un error que se soluciono usando hilos porque la tarea era muy grande, entonces todo en un solo hilo secundario?